# Running multiple commands on EC2 using psexec and AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, psexec

I'm trying to use CMD script to run two commands on Amazon EC2s using "psexec" command to run specific batch file to download specific file on these machines and the other command triggers .exe file to update SVN project, the problem is the current script runs the first action only and ignoring the other part of the "&&"

How can I make both actions run command, P.S I'm using FOR loop to run it on many EC2s?

Here is the script I'm using:

FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (D:\serverslist.txt) DO (psexec -u Administrator -p "password" \%%i -i "C:\project\script.bat" & "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"C:\project\" /closeonend:1)
pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used ^&^& instead of && and it is working.

The working script:

FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (D:\serverslist.txt) DO (psexec -u Administrator -p "password" \%%i -i "C:\project\script.bat" ^&^& "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"C:\project\" /closeonend:1) pause
pause

Answer (score 0):

You can try PowerShell Workflow .. Parallel processing

[Parallel processing with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell/)